# Explode and process values as an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

When clicking a div I need to store a few data into a hidden input field
the data will take the form like this

```
term_name:has_children:parent_id|
```

As more divs are clicked their will be more data

```
postA:1:275|postB:0:375
```

etc,
how do i split this into an array for processing?
With php i would simply do

```
explode ('|','string');
```

I would need to do this twice here once with '|' and then again with ':'

I hope my question is clear. Please let me know if it is not
Thank You in Advance

Comment: `var newArray = string.split("|");` and you repeat that split in each "newArray" element. If you're using jquery you may also either use .each or .map for such a thing. What do you need to do after splitting?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I need to process it in a way that
1) I have to check every for every div in the current document depending on term_name. 
2) then check if term name has_children 
3) is term_name has_children then take the parentID and find corresponding children through an Ajax call
then find the Children in current document and add a few classes to those children

I was hoping to do something like break it into arrays and sub-arrays however i'm not that good in javascript. if you have a suggestion i'm open to ideas